# AgGrid rows count when rowGroup is true

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

When rowGroup applied to any column in aggrid, and 
`statusPanel: 'agTotalAndFilteredRowCountComponent'`,rows counts display like this in footer

rows : X of Y

but i want sow only X , how to achieve this ? agFilteredRowCountComponent doesn't show anything. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the goal in two ways:

**1.** use already defined ag-grid component

```js
{ statusPanel: 'agTotalAndFilteredRowCountComponent', align: 'left' }
```

**2.** Define your custom `StatusBarComponent`:

```js
statusPanels: [
p   { statusPanel: StatusBarComponent, align: 'left' },
    ...
]
```

Please note, that this is a simple example of implementation related to your issue - full review of the problem probably will take andvantage of different Grid Events like 'filterChanged', implement 'getTotalRowCountValue' or 'onDataChanged' methods etc.

[Working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/5oZsEtgHs2LMv9BREc7S?p=preview)